# Bokeh: Plots with Select widgets isn't updating the plots in bokeh server when the axes are changed

Tags: python, bokeh

EDIT: Added a minimal working example code to reproduce the issue.

df has columns like trip, driverName, carRegNo, totalDistanceTravelled, totalTimeTaken etc. I want to have plots 'Drivers vs Distance Travelled', 'Drivers vs Time taken' upon changing x and/or y axis. Likewise for 'Car Reg No.' against Distance and Time Taken.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc

trip_data = [{"trip": '1', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.66", "totalTimeTaken": "765083","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '2', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.63", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '3', "totalDistanceTravelled": "3.66", "totalTimeTaken": "602713","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"},
             {"trip": '4', "totalDistanceTravelled": "7.11", "totalTimeTaken": "2234282","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '5', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.14", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '6', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.33", "totalTimeTaken": "748446","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '7', "totalDistanceTravelled": "10.66", "totalTimeTaken": "960362","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(trip_data)
drivers = df['driverName'].str.strip()
vehicles = df['carRegNo'].str.strip()
time_stamp = df['time'].astype(float)
total_distance_travelled = df['totalDistanceTravelled'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] = df['totalTimeTaken'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] /= 1000 * 3600

# Create Input controls
x_axis = Select(title="X Axis", options=sorted(["Drivers", "Vehicle Reg. Number"]), value="Drivers")
y_axis = Select(title="Y Axis", options=sorted(["Distance Travelled (kms)", "Time Taken (hours)"]), value="Time Taken (hours)")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))


def update():
    col_key_values = {
        "Time Taken (hours)": 'totalTimeTaken',
        "Distance Travelled (kms)": 'totalDistanceTravelled'
    }

    x_map = {
        "Drivers": drivers,
        "Vehicle Reg. Number": vehicles
    }

    x_name = x_map[x_axis.value]
    x_y_values = {}
    for x in x_name.unique():
        x_y_values[x] = round(df.loc[x_name == x, col_key_values[y_axis.value]].astype(float).sum(), 2)

    source.data = dict(
        x=x_y_values.keys(),
        y=x_y_values.values()
    )
    print source.data

update()  # initial load of the data
p = figure(x_range=source.data['x'], plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="", toolbar_location=None)
p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)
controls = [x_axis, y_axis]
for control in controls:
    print 'control: ', control.value
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

sizing_mode = 'fixed'
inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

l = layout(children=[[inputs, p]],sizing_mode='fixed')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Travel Data"
```

This code renders a plot with the default settings i.e., Drivers vs Time Taken, but upon changing the x-axis to "Vehicle Reg. Number" the plot doesn't get updated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running this with `bokeh serve app.py`? Have you tried putting print statements in the callback to verify that it is running when you expect, and generating the new data you expect?

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it on the bokeh server. I did put print statements, within the update() function, and after layout creation. The statements within update() were printing the new data whereas the ones outside didn't even print anything. I was wondering if the execution point was even reaching there.

Comment: I would not be concerned so much about the print statements outside the callback. The bokeh server runs the script and it is similar but not entirely identical to a normal python execution. It's hard to say where the usage error is without running code. If you can put a complete minimal reproducing example somere e.g. in a gist, I can try it out.

Comment: I have included an example to reproduce the issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It escaped my notice that you are using a Categorical range for the X-axis. A categorical range is defined by the listed factors, and only those factors. So if you want to update the data to use coordinates from a *different* set of factors, then you need to update the range as well. Otherwise, the situation you have with the code above is that you are trying to plot data values to x-coordinates that don't exist, as far as the range and plot know.

Here is a modified version of your script that I believe behaves as you intend (note, I use py3 so it's been updated for that as well):

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc

trip_data = [{"trip": '1', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.66", "totalTimeTaken": "765083","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '2', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.63", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '3', "totalDistanceTravelled": "3.66", "totalTimeTaken": "602713","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"},
             {"trip": '4', "totalDistanceTravelled": "7.11", "totalTimeTaken": "2234282","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '5', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.14", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '6', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.33", "totalTimeTaken": "748446","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '7', "totalDistanceTravelled": "10.66", "totalTimeTaken": "960362","time": "1504189219256", "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(trip_data)
drivers = df['driverName'].str.strip()
vehicles = df['carRegNo'].str.strip()
time_stamp = df['time'].astype(float)
total_distance_travelled = df['totalDistanceTravelled'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] = df['totalTimeTaken'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] /= 1000 * 3600

# Create Input controls
x_axis = Select(title="X Axis", options=sorted(["Drivers", "Vehicle Reg. Number"]), value="Drivers")
y_axis = Select(title="Y Axis", options=sorted(["Distance Travelled (kms)", "Time Taken (hours)"]), value="Time Taken (hours)")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))

p = figure(x_range=source.data['x'], plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="", toolbar_location=None)

def update():
    col_key_values = {
        "Time Taken (hours)": 'totalTimeTaken',
        "Distance Travelled (kms)": 'totalDistanceTravelled'
    }

    x_map = {
        "Drivers": drivers,
        "Vehicle Reg. Number": vehicles
    }

    x_name = x_map[x_axis.value]
    x_y_values = {}
    for x in x_name.unique():
        x_y_values[x] = round(df.loc[x_name == x, col_key_values[y_axis.value]].astype(float).sum(), 2)

    p.x_range.factors = list(x_y_values.keys())
    source.data = dict(
        x=list(x_y_values.keys()),
        y=list(x_y_values.values())
    )
    print(source.data)
    print(p.x_range.factors)

update()  # initial load of the data
p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)
controls = [x_axis, y_axis]
for control in controls:
    print('control: ', control.value)
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

sizing_mode = 'fixed'
inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

l = layout(children=[[inputs, p]],sizing_mode='fixed')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Travel Data"
```

This is the important line that was added:

```
p.x_range.factors = list(x_y_values.keys())
```

That tells the x-axis range what the new valid factor names are, so when you change to data that uses theses new factors, it knows where they should go. I should add, I think Bokeh is a little sensative to the order of updates here: updating the factors first works, but updating the data first seems not to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works :)
I thought p = figure(x_range=source.data['x'], plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="", toolbar_location=None) would have taken care of updating x_range. Any reason why this isn't the case?

Comment: The script is only executed *once*, when session is initiated by a connection, and the `Document` is created. Only the callbacks run more, in response to events. That line executes when a browser hits a page an opens a session, and never again (for that session)

Comment: I did upvote it. But my reputation isn't enough for it to be displayed. I am very sorry. Thank you very much for patiently answering my question.